# Set replication in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I was trying loading file using hadoop API as an experiment.

I want to set replication to minimum as this one is for experiment. 
I first tried this with `FileSystem.setReplication()`:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.set("fs.defaultFS","hdfs://192.168.248.166:8020");
FileSystem dfs2 = FileSystem.get(config);
Path src2 = new Path("C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\testfile.txt");
Path dst2 = new Path(dfs2.getWorkingDirectory()+"/tempdir");
dfs2.copyFromLocalFile(src2, dst2);
dfs2.setReplication(dst2, (short)1);  /**setting replication**/
```

The replica was shown as 1, but it was available on 3 datanodes.

When I tried it with `Configuration.set()`:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.set("fs.defaultFS","hdfs://192.168.248.166:8020");
config.set("dfs.replication", "1");  /**setting replication**/
FileSystem dfs2 = FileSystem.get(config);
Path src2 = new Path("C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\testfile.txt");
Path dst2 = new Path(dfs2.getWorkingDirectory()+"/tempdir");
```

This gave the desired outcome (1 replica available on 1 datanode)

Why there are two APIs for the same thing?
What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `Filesystem`'s [setReplication()](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#setReplication%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20short%29) sets the replication of an existing file on HDFS. In your case, you first copy the local file `testFile.txt` to HDFS, using the default replication factor (3) and then change the replication factor of this file to 1. After this command, it takes a while until the over-replicated blocks get deleted. ([source](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html#Decrease+Replication+Factor))

On the other hand, when you use the `config.set("dfs.replication", "1");` command to set the replication, you can copy the local file *after* that, so its blocks get copied just once, from the first time.

In other words, I believe (but I might be wrong) that both commands have the same final result, but you have to wait a little bit until the first one is carried out.

Comment: Yes. It first created 3 replicas though I did not waited to reduce it down to 1. Why the default replication factor is 3? I specified 2 in hdfs-site.xml. What I mean is though I kept replication factor to 2 in hdfs-site.xml, it still creates 3 copies when I use Java API to load data. Why I need to explicitly call `configuration.set("DFS. replication",1)` each time in code?

Comment: @Mahesha999 So, if you use the hadoop shell commands (not the Java API), e.g., to copyFromLocal, the replication factor is 2, but when using Java it's 3? If yes, I don't have an explanation for that. If no, perhaps you are changing a wrong file. `hdfs-site.xml` *should* do what you wish, without explicitly setting this parameter each time in your code. I also assume that you have not changed `dfs.replication.max`. Correct?